# Fastlane Precheck fails with unexpected error. Can I skip it?

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

Fastlane is being brittle.. again.. it is blocking the release of my app. Is there any way to skip precheck?

What I've tried:

- setting all settings to skip for precheck
- searching the precheck and deliver documentation

Here is the output of `bundle exec fastlane precheck`, any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
 developer@developer-MacBook-Pro  ~/Projects/someApp   master ●  bundle exec fastlane precheck                                                             1 ↵  536  17:47:17 
[✔]  
[17:47:32]: Successfully loaded '/Users/somedeveloper/Projects/someApp/fastlane/Precheckfile' 

+------------------------------------------------+
| Detected Values from './fastlane/Precheckfile' |
+--------------------------+---------------------+
| negative_apple_sentiment | {:level=>:skip}     |
| curse_words              | {:level=>:skip}     |
| future_functionality     | {:level=>:skip}     |
| other_platforms          | {:level=>:skip}     |
| placeholder_text         | {:level=>:skip}     |
| test_words               | {:level=>:skip}     |
| unreachable_urls         | {:level=>:skip}     |
+--------------------------+---------------------+


+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                Summary for precheck 2.219.0                |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------+
| app_identifier                 | com.someApp|
| username                       | somedeveloper@gmail.com  |
| team_id                        | 11111111                 |
| platform                       | ios                       |
| default_rule_level             | error                     |
| include_in_app_purchases       | true                      |
| use_live                       | false                     |
| negative_apple_sentiment.level | skip                      |
| placeholder_text.level         | skip                      |
| other_platforms.level          | skip                      |
| future_functionality.level     | skip                      |
| test_words.level               | skip                      |
| curse_words.level              | skip                      |
| unreachable_urls.level         | skip                      |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------+

[17:47:32]: Starting login with user 'somedeveloper@gmail.com'
[17:47:35]: Successfully logged in
[17:47:35]: Checking app for precheck rule violations
[17:47:38]: Reading in-app purchases. If you have a lot, this might take a while
[17:47:38]: You can disable IAP checking by setting the `include_in_app_purchases` flag to `false`

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...

➡️  Fastlane Precheck Failure - Unexpected Response
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/21866 [open] 0 
    a day ago

➡️  [spaceship] Creation of in-app purchases returns NotFound error
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/19140 [open] 10 
    04 Aug 2021

➡️  create InAppPurchase product failure
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20933 [open] 3 
    24 Jun 2023

and 23 more at: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/search?q=%7B%22data%22%3D%3Enil%2C%20%22messages%22%3D%3E%7B%22warn%22%3D%3Enil%2C%20%22error%22%3D%3E%5B%22Not%20Found%22%5D%2C%20%22info%22%3D%3Enil%7D%2C%20%22statusCode%22%3D%3E%22ERROR%22%7D&type=Issues&utf8=✓

  You can ⌘ + double-click on links to open them directly in your browser.
bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/usr/local/bin/fastlane)
Spaceship::UnexpectedResponse: [!] {"data"=>nil, "messages"=>{"warn"=>nil, "error"=>["Not Found"], "info"=>nil}, "statusCode"=>"ERROR"}
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:793:in `parse_response'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/tunes/tunes_client.rb:1320:in `load_iap'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/tunes/iap_list.rb:59:in `edit'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/precheck/lib/precheck/rule_processor.rb:166:in `block in generate_app_items_to_check'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/precheck/lib/precheck/rule_processor.rb:165:in `each'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/precheck/lib/precheck/rule_processor.rb:165:in `generate_app_items_to_check'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/precheck/lib/precheck/rule_processor.rb:47:in `process_app_and_version'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/precheck/lib/precheck/runner.rb:126:in `check_for_rule_violations'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/precheck/lib/precheck/runner.rb:58:in `run'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/precheck/lib/precheck/commands_generator.rb:42:in `block (2 levels) in run'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:187:in `call'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:157:in `run'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/runner.rb:444:in `run_active_command'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:124:in `run!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/delegates.rb:18:in `run!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/precheck/lib/precheck/commands_generator.rb:72:in `run'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/precheck/lib/precheck/commands_generator.rb:20:in `start'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:115:in `take_off'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.219.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
```